# Order - Differential Eqautions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Determine whether the equations are linear or non-linear and give the order.

$$x^3 \frac{d^3y}{dx^3} - x \left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^3 + y = 0$$

$$\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} + 5xy=e^x .$$

Answer (score 1):

The first differential equation is not linear (since $y'$ is not linear) and of order $3$. The second ode is linear and of order $2$.